# SharePoint SPFx - Creating comment section using textarea field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I'm building a SharePoint SPFx using react.

In one of my components I want to have a comment section. Where a user can write a comment and then submit it to my `Multiple lines of text` field called `comments`. I currently have `Append Changes to Existing Text` set to `Yes.

Below I have a `textarea` to allow users to type a comment and then on submit I'm sending that comment to the comment field. However when someone submits another comment will this erase previous comments?

```
//Area to add comment
<textarea 
    value={this.state.Comments} 
    onChange={this.handleChangeComments}
    rows={10}
    required 
/>

<button onClick={this.submitComment.bind(this)}>Submit</button>

//Function to submit comment 
submitComment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests").items.getById(120).update({
        Comments: this.state.Comments,              
    }).then(i => {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

On another component I will make a call to display the comments and want it to look something similar to this:

```
<h4>Comments Below</h4>
<div>
   <p>First comment here</p>
   <p>07/12/2020 (get the date of submission I have a get_date function)</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Second comment here that was left</p>
   <p>07/10/2020</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>Another comment here</p>
   <p>06/8/2020</p>
</div>
```

So I want that field to continue to hold all comments submitted and a way to `loop` through each one. For comments I don't see there being any long comments or more than 10 comments added.

I was using this for reference: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-track-comments-with-append-changes-functionality-in-sharepoint-list/

Answer (score 0):

PnP open-source projects offer a sample web part "Advanced Comments Box" that provided comment feature.

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/js-advanced-commenting/README.md

With a little modification, you can configure this comment box for every section.

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/js-advanced-commenting/README.md

[image]